# Will PHP json_decode() always preserve the array order from a JSON array?

Tags: php, json

Does the string

```
 ["first","second","third"]
```

always preserve array order and result in the PHP array

```
array('first','second','third');
```

when using `json_decode()`?  I realize the answer is **NO for objects**, but I am asking about a string representing an **array** as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Arrays are ordered by definition, and JSON preserves this.

The [JSON specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) says:

> An array structure is a pair of square bracket tokens surrounding zero or more values. The values are 
>   separated by commas. The order of the values is significant.

The last sentence implies that a JSON encoder or decoder that changes the order is not in conformance with the specification. I can't find anything in the PHP documentation that explicitly says that it observes this requirement, but I think it can be assumed since it claims to be implementing JSON.

Comment: So the JSON array is ordered by definition, but does the PHP language guarantee the deserialization process will preserve this order?  Java has libraries which use multi-threading to deserialize faster, and these multi-threading deserialization engines do not preserve order on an ordered array during the conversion process.  I'm looking for a guarantee from the PHP language.

Comment: I've added material from the JSON specification that implies that a valid JSON decoder must preserve order. I hope the Java libraries don't reorder things by default, but only when allowed to by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes order will be kept.

Alternatively you can use  cast array to object, as order of object variables are not modified `json_encode((object)$arr)`.

Comment: I specified I was not asking about objects, only arrays.

Comment: No such thing as associative array in JavaScript.

Comment: @Havenard Unfortunately they do exist. `..PHP arrays can contain integer and string keys at the same time as PHP does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays....`,http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: This is PHP. I'm talking about JavaScript. JSON is a variable declaration in JavaScript synthax, therefore there is no associative array support. It will implicitly convert any attempt to declare an associative array into an object.

Comment: @Havenard Ok. i knew it already.Every array is index associated to object.

Comment: not only the question wasnt' about object, but the answer he gave is wrong. 
objects' PROPERTIES ORDER will NOT BE PRESEVED when doing json_decode.